# Audio file sharing in ESP32 over BLE

Tags: android, embedded, esp32, arduino-ide

I want to send a audio file (MUSIC) from my mobile (Android) over BLUETOOTH. First of all that file should save in sd (memory) card and then same file (signal) should go to I2S amplifier (speaker). Does anyone know how I can receive the file with the ESP32 and save it into sd (memory) card?

(Is it possible to send audio files over BLUETOOTH in esp32 and store it in sd card and send same signal to amplifier (for speaker))

Best regards  PM030

Answer (score 1):

BLE is not really meant for large file transfer due to the limitation of its maximum packet size. Thus to send big files, you will need good libraries at the other end that could piece together all the small parts of the big file that is send one at a time.

Having said that, some people has send image files over like this. You may want to check this out: https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/mx7x31/file_transfer_using_bluetooth_classic_esp32_sd/

This is the related github code that may be useful for you: https://github.com/frankcohen/ReflectionsOS/blob/main/Gateway/ESP32FileTransfer/ESP32FileTransfer.ino

The concerned author of this above project even has given his own android app: https://github.com/frankcohen/ReflectionsOS/tree/main/Gateway

I know this might not be the answer you are looking for, but the above links may prove useful to gain some direction.

Thank You
Naveen PS